# which method is faster to increase page speed by re sizing remote PNG images in php.?

Tags: php, mysql, png, image-resizing

Introduction: My Webpage shows the remote server PNG images of Size 90 by 90. I want to re-size it to 50 by 50. There are 300 of images on single webpage which make it slow. Normally My Webpage daily opens by 2k users.

By Searching a Lot I Found these methods but I don't Know Which is Better Please help..
Here Are My Approaches:

1. On The Fly.
2. re-size and Save it to database.
3. re-size and save it to my web directory.

I am using mysql to fetch rows each row has name, 'url to image', id , time, description. This 'url to image' is my problem.
I think Saving to MYSQL Database is good which make retrieving from it easier and maybe faster than others.

Please provide me any idea of coding where to start. I am Trying this image re-sizing for first time..

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well :

- On the fly : slow and incredibly ineficient, as you saw
- Save on database : are you out of your mind, do NOT save images in DB
- Save in web directory : that's my boy. Resize the image the first time it is accessed and cache it on your directory. Next time, you won't have to download it and resize, just serve it. Delete useless files every week or so.

Comment: any idea to start coding for png re-sizing i found lots of tutorial for jpg

Answer (score 2):

Go with #3, don't store images in a database, and if you have much views and many images, doing it on the fly isn't very effective.

No, do it once, and save it to the filesystem, with a link in the database like you have now.

Also, if possible, do it as soon as a new image is uploaded.

Comment: these images are fetch from facebook. So how the code goes any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't personally save the image to the database, but that is more my personal choice.

I would probably opt for resizing them all and saving them out to the website, and returning the correct images than resizing on the fly. If you're always going to be returning the image in 50x50, why are they uploaded as 90x90 in the first place? Can't you resize them when you upload them?